# Rounded image as output in react-cropper

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get rounded image in output in react-cropper. I have cropped the image using css but I wan t to send rounded image to server. The cropping using css sends square image.

```
.cropper-crop-box, .cropper-view-box {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

.cropper-view-box {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #39f;
    outline: 0;
 }
```

This only crops the cropper not the image.

Comment: This is CSS which is only useful for editing original images on browser. It does not alter the image in anyway. The original image is still intact and square.You will have to change the image itself for the client to send a rounded image to server

Comment: I'm getting base64 output from cropper, how will I round that image itself?

Comment: what should be the extra space be filled with? an image is always rectangular. should it be filled with with or transparent? what server language are u using?